# Is returning a value and not storing it to a variable considered bad practice?

Tags: javascript

Given the following function:

```
  function lamePathValidator(path) {
    if (typeof path !== 'string') {
      throw new TypeError(`Invalid path "${path}": should be a string.`);
    }

    return path;
  }
```

Is it considered bad practice if occasionally it's being used without storing the return value to a variable?

```
...
lamePathValidator('./data');
...
```

**Edit**: The only use case in which I need the returned value, is for property assignments in constructors, such as:

```
constructor(basepath) {
  this._basepath = this._validatePath(basepath);
}
```

I could of course write:

```
constructor(basepath) {
  this._validatePath(basepath)
  this._basepath = basepath;
}
```

The former block is more concise though.

**Edit #2**:
I could also pass constructor parameters to a `_validateAll(params)` function since none of them are actually being altered in any way. It's "validate", not "sanitize" after all. :)

Comment: Why does this function return anything? The return value is useless.

Comment: The comment indicates that you did not understand the question.

Comment: It's not inherently bad practice - however, I think it makes more sense to `throw` or not `throw` **OR** return `true` or `false` in this particular case, since your function is not returning anything useful.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to maintain the [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but I'm not sure you got the "C" for "Complete" in there. Could you explain a little more about your use case, or a general use-case?

Comment: @TecBrat The return value is only assigned to props in constructors. (see edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of functions that return data that is not always useful, but sometimes is.  In those cases not storing the output when you don't need it makes sense.

However if the return value is never useful then you shouldn't be returning it in the first place.  In your example function the path is not altered so there is no reason to return it, the calling code already has it.

Comment: I see. Since input = output, get rid of the output. Thanks. :)

Comment: I interpreted the question like the OP is the writer of the function.

Comment: Even if the OP does write the function if it's called in 2 different places and one of those places cares about the output and the other doesn't then the function should return something, but not always store the output.

Comment: We do not know if the function is called in multiple places. If it is, I would make two functions of it anyway and extract common pieces of those into helper functions.

Comment: @Kootoopas: *"Since input = output, get rid of the output."* It's not as simple as that. Sometimes it's entirely appropriate for a function to return an argument unchanged. The question can't be answered in a vacuum.

Comment: I do not think it adds to the question if the return value is calculated or just reflected.

Answer (score 1):

A function can return a value if required. **It is not mandatory to return some value from it.** In your case there is no need to return any value.

Read the js function documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Comment: The question was if it is a good practice to sometimes not care about the return value.